# Lots of 'type or namespace' errors using git

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, git, visual-studio-2015

I used the Github windows application to publish a VS c# project, and then clone it on another computer to continue working.

The first computer is a Windows 7 64bit SP1 running VS 2015 community edition.
The second is Windows 8.1 64bit running VS 2015 community edition.
The first computer can build the project, however when I tried to clone and build on the second computer I get 245 errors, mostly consisting of

> the type or namespace error 'xxx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

both computers regedit show I have version 4.6.00057 .NET framework installed. Their regedit entries are identical. I have checked in the properties of the solution of both computers and they both target the .NET framework 4.5.2.

How can I fix the second computer build? Is github a bad application to be using with VS solutions? (I am very new to C#, ASP.NET, and VS).

Comment: How are you building? What kind of project? (Console app? Windows Phone app? WPF? WinForms? ASP.NET?) What exactly are the errors? No, github works fine with .NET code.

Comment: check your references. escpeially NuGet ones.

Comment: It is an ASP.NET Web Application. 
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'GlobalFilterCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). The rest are the same but refer to different names e.g. Authorize, Controller, AllowAnonymous, etc. I am simply loading the project/solution and selecting build.

Comment: Probably the namespace giving the errors are 3rd party.

Comment: @Szer, how do I check my references? And what is NuGet? Sorry I am new to Visual Studio/C#

Comment: @Dev-One there are no 3rd party libraries references as far as I know.. This is a standard project and I have been following the MSDN tutorials

Comment: What on earth is gonig on? This is driving me crazy. I even switched to the team foundation server to share my files. The exact same thing is happening, hundreds and hundreds of errors when I build. I even try to use the suggested fixes and it just creates more errors. This is happening with a brand new BLANK ASP.NET MVC project.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC *does* make use of a lot of nuget packages.  If these aren't checked in to source control (usually the /packages folder), then they should automatically be restored when building.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that worked was to manually copy my files to a USB and open them on the second computer.
Source control sucks. Git doesn't work. Inbuilt source control on VS doesn't work.

I'm surprised no one else has ever tried to share projects between computers.
I'll be using google drive from now on

Comment: They do.  All the time.  It works.  I use git with GitHub every day and don't have these problems.

Comment: While I understand that it can be frustrating learning a new technology, I would strongly advise that you figure out what the root problem really is, rather than copying all your files to a shared drive. Source control may "suck," but lack of source control sucks even more. Chances are you just did not add a file to source control that was needed for the build.